# Software implementation of floating point division, issues with rounding

Tags: c++, algorithm, floating-point

As a learning project I am implementing floating point operations (add, sub, mul, div) in software using c++. The goal is to be more comfortable with the underlying details of floating point behavior.

I am trying to match my processor operations to the exact bit, meaning IEEE 754 standard. So far it has been working great, add, sub and mult behave perfectly, I tested it on around 110 million random operations and got the same exact result to what the processor does in hardware. (Although did not take into account edge cases, overflow etc).

After that, I started moving to the last operation, division. It works fine and achieves the wanted result, but from time to time, I get the last mantissa bit wrong, not rounded up. I am having a bit of hard time understanding why.
The main reference I have been using is the great talk from **John Farrier** (the time stamp is at the point where it shows how to round):

https://youtu.be/k12BJGSc2Nc?t=1153

That rounding has been working really well for all operation but is giving me troubles for the division. 
Let me give you a specific example.
I am trying to divide 645.68011474609375 by 493.20962524414063

The final result I get is :

mine :  0-01111111-0100111100100011110000**0**

c++_  :  0-01111111-0100111100100011110000**1**

As you can see everything matches except for the last bit. The way I am computing the division is based on this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fi8A4zz1d-s

Following this, I compute 28 bits off accuracy 24 of mantissa ( hidden one + 23 mantissa) and the 3 bits for guard, round sticky plus an extra one for the possible shift.
Using the algorithm of the video, I can at maximum get a normalization shift of 1, that s why I have an extra bit at the end in case gets shifted in in the normalization, so will be available in the rounding. Now here is the result I get from the division algorithm:

```
 010100111100100011110000 0100
 ------------------------ ----
 ^                        grs^
 |__ to be normalized        |____ extra bit
```

As you can see I get a 0 in the 24th position, so I will need to shift on the left by one to get the correct normalization. 
This mean I will get:

```
10100111100100011110000 100
```

Based on the video of John Farrier, in the case of **100** grs bits, I only normalize if the LSB of the mantissa is a 1. In my case is a zero, and that is why I do not round up my result.

The reason why I am a bit lost is that I am sure my algorithm is computing the right mantissa, I have double checked it with online calculators, the rounding strategy works for all the other operations. Also, computing in this way, triggers the normalization, which yields, in the end, the correct exponent.

Am I missing something ? a small detail somewhere?

One thing that strikes me as odd is the sticky bits, in the addition and multiplication you get a different degree of shifting, which leads to higher chances of the sticky bits to trigger, in this case here, I shift only by one maximum which puts the sticky bits as to be not really sticky.

I do hope I gave enough details to make my problem understood. Here you can find at the bottom my division implementation, is a bit filled with prints I am using for debugging but should give an idea of what I am doing, the code starts at line 374:

https://gist.github.com/giordi91/1388504fadcf94b3f6f42103dfd1f938

PS: meanwhile I am going through the "everything scientist should know about floating point numbers" in order to see if I missed something.

Comment: "should give an idea of what I am doing" - we strongly prefer the exact code, cleaned up, in the question itself. I can see why you're hesitant to add it to the question now - that's already very long. But that's because it's rather big on words. We trust you can implement addition, no need to tell us.

Comment: sure thing, I removed the code that was not directly related to the division from the gist.

Comment: Check how the C++ code is doing float operations for example with doubles the Intel FPU can use 80 bits (not 64) there maybe a similar extensions for float.  Also there are compiler flags to control the precision/accuracy of float and double operations.  Also this blog has lots of information on implementation errors/issues and edge cases: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/

Comment: @RichardCritten thanks for the reply, I do know that blog post, I am slowly working my way through, in my specific case, I have computed extra 4 bits mantissa, that under the grs rounding scheme to even is the only bits I need. So even if I round up or down the extra bits of mantissa there is not carrying that would make the sticky bit to flip making the round to occur. That s where I am stuck at the moment, the extra bits of accuracy won't help me. Meanwhile, I will try to dig out useful information from that blog. If interested I can print out many more bits of accuracy from the mantissa.

Comment: www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/TestFloat.html as well as SoftFloat same author, source code for beating up on a floating point unit as well as a soft float library, so there may be something of interest there to show how he did it.

Comment: maybe you want to add/shift a couple of bits on the numerator before doing the fixed point divide, giving you a result that is 4 or so times too large, then you can examine/round before shifting those back off ( x/y = (4x/4y) = (4x/y)/4 ).  could leave many bits 5 or 8 or 16, ...

Comment: What's the reason that you use bit-by-bit division? You could utilize integer division, so your code will be much faster. And use the remainder to decide rounding direction.

Comment: @old_timer interesting approach, that would make the sticky bit to some work, i will test it.

Comment: @geza right now the focus is not on performance but correctness, once the algorithm is solid I will see how to make it faster.

Comment: Hmm.. With integer division the code is simpler, faster, and surely solid (you just need to check out the remainder, as far as I know). It is better in every way... This code doesn't need long division, where bit-by-bit division is common (I could be wrong, of course, I've never implemented SW floating point - but I currently don't see the point of bit-by-bit division).

Comment: The point is simply learning, when I implemented multiplication, I started with the n^2 bit multiplication, then moved to just shift the whole number in and add. Ideally, at one point, I would like to get to the point where I don't use any hardware operation, but even addition is implemented in software. Utterly useless but a fun exercise. I will most likely implement as you say. To be honest I did not think of it and is a great idea. thank you for it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result you get from the division algorithm is inadequate. You show:

```
 010100111100100011110000 0100
 ------------------------ ----
 ^                        grs^
 |__ to be normalized        |____ extra bit
```

The mathematically exact quotient continues:

```
 010100111100100011110000 0100 110000111100100100011110…
```

Thus, the residue at the point where you are rounding exceeds ½ ULP, so it should be rounded up. I did not study your code in detail, but it looks like you may have just calculated an extra bit or two of the significand<sup>1</sup>. You actually need to know that the residue is non-zero, not just whether its next bit or two is zero. The final sticky bit should be one if **any** of the bits at or beyond that position in the exact mathematical result would be non-zero.

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> “Significand” is the preferred term. “Mantissa” is a legacy term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. The significand of a floating-point value is linear. A mantissa is logarithmic.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, and thank you for the correction on mantissa vs significand, I did not know the "legacy" meaning of it.
The solution you propose with "any" of the extra bit after the grs to influence the sticky makes so much sense!  I am gonna try and let you know. I wonder how many extra bits of precision are needed. Anyone know what modern CPU do in hardware in that regards?

Comment: thank you, good sir, for the help, looks like your solution worked, right know it is crunchy division and all pass, it has done 86 millions one and counting. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MarcoGiordano You should not use any finite number of extra bits. "any of the bits at or beyond that position in the exact mathematical result would be non-zero" is exactly equivalent to "the current remainder is non-zero".

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan interesting, so you are telling me if I get a reminder after computing the grs bits I just set the sticky bits?